# How to stop javascript increment?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making this simple project, when I mouse over the div it will expand the div but I want to expand this div till the end of the web page and don't want to cross the web page.

HTML

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
        background-color: black;
      }
      .center {
        width: 1%;
        transform-origin: right;
        height: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: green;
        left: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
      }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 let div = document.querySelector("div");
      let indx = 0;
      div.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
        indx++;

        div.style.width = indx + "%";
        console.log(indx);
        if (indx === 200) {
          indx = 200;
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want 200 to be the maximum value you have to check if it goes over 200 and then set it to 200

```
let div = document.querySelector("div");
let indx = 0;
div.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    indx++;
    if (indx > 200) {
        indx = 200;
    }

    div.style.width = indx + "%";
    console.log(indx);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your horizontal center doesn't work, and it is strange to use 200% for 100% space..

```
div.onmousemove =e=>{
  if (indx < 100) {
    div.style.width = ++indx + "%"
    console.clear();
    console.log(indx,'%')
  }
}
```

**PS:** CSS changing (real center H & V ):

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  height: 20px;
  width: 1%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div")
let indx = 1

div.onmousemove =e=>{
  if (indx < 100) {
    div.style.width = ++indx + "%"
    console.clear()
    console.log(indx,'%')
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  height: 20px;
  width: 1%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

or the same, but with remove EventListener

```
div.addEventListener("mousemove", DivGrow )

function DivGrow(e) {
  if (indx < 100) {
    div.style.width = ++indx + "%"
    console.clear()
    console.log(indx,'%')
  } else {
    div.removeEventListener("mousemove", DivGrow )
  }
}
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div")
let indx = 1

div.addEventListener("mousemove", DivGrow )

function DivGrow(e)
{
  if (indx < 100)
  {
    div.style.width = ++indx + "%";
    console.clear()
    console.log(indx,'%')
  }
  else
  {
    div.removeEventListener("mousemove", DivGrow )
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  height: 20px;
  width: 1%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```